# Automatically connecting adjacent tcolorboxes

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

I would like some adjacent `tcolorbox`es to be connected, but not by using the option `beforeafter skip=0pt`, because I also want those boxes to have normal spacing from other text. That is, I expect the boxes as in this picture:

[image]

automatically changing to the looking in the picture below:

[image]

How can one achieve this?

Below is a MWE to play with.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{definition}{enhanced jigsaw,pad at break*=1mm,breakable,
left=4mm,right=4mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
% beforeafter skip balanced=0pt,
colback=orange!10,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={1.5mm}{-1mm}{green!50!black},arc=.7mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
    ...
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
    \blindtext
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

---

**Old**:

I have written the following (very ugly) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

% \newenvironment{testbox}
% {\begin{tcolorbox}
% [enhanced jigsaw,pad at break*=1mm,breakable,
% colback=orange!10!white,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
% borderline west={1.5mm}{-1mm}{green}]}
% {\end{tcolorbox}}

\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newlength{\deftop}
\newlength{\defbot}
\newlength{\defsep}
\newcounter{def}

\newenvironment{testbox}
{\vspace{-1mm}\begin{tcolorbox}[blank,breakable]
\stepcounter{def}
\zsavepos{def\arabic{def}1}
\setlength{\global\deftop}{
  \dimexpr\paperheight - \zposy{def\arabic{def}1} sp}
\setlength{\global\defsep}{\deftop-\defbot}
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\defsep > -0.1mm}}
  {\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\defsep < 3mm}}{\vspace{-4mm}}{}}
  {}\par
  % This should be a dynamical quantity,
  % adjusting according to the page's situation
\begin{tcolorbox}
[enhanced jigsaw,pad at break*=1mm,breakable,
colback=orange!10!white,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={1.5mm}{-1mm}{green}]}
{\end{tcolorbox}
\zsavepos{def\arabic{def}2}
\setlength{\global\defbot}{
  \dimexpr\paperheight - \zposy{def\arabic{def}2} sp}
\end{tcolorbox}\vspace{-1mm}}

\begin{document}
    Some texts.
    \begin{testbox}box 1\end{testbox}
    Some texts.
    \begin{testbox}box 2\end{testbox}%\vspace{-4mm}
    \begin{testbox}box 3\end{testbox}
\end{document}
```

It uses `zref` to record the position of each box so as to check whether two boxes are adjacent. However this solution does **not** always work. This code doesn't check if two boxes are on the same page (I did write a version that tries to check the page number issue, but since page number checking in LaTeX doesn't work pretty well on the edge of the page, I disgarded it). Also, the `4mm` is not a good idea because sometimes when a page is very loose, `\vspace{4mm}` is not enough to connect them.

I wish to know if you have a better and prettier way to achieve this effect.

Comment: Why do you need two independent colorboxes for box2 and box3? One tcolorbox with `box2\\ box3` could work.

Comment: @Ignasi Actually I'm writing a documentclass and this is part of my `definition` environment. When there're adjacent definitions I want them to be connected. If put in one box, the appearance of those definitions would be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using my new favourite tool in `expl3`'s arsenal: `\peek_analysis_map_inline:n`.  It allows you to scan the input stream token by token, letting you act on each one as required.  The `\ScanEnv` command:

```latex
\ScanEnv [*] {<env>} {<true>} {<false>}
```

looks ahead in the token stream, ignoring spaces (and if `*` is given, ignoring `\par`), looking for `\begin{<env>}`.  If that is found, it inserts the code `<true>` before the ignored spaces and `\par`.  If the environment is not found, the `<false>` code is inserted instead.

With that, you can do what you want with

```latex
\ScanEnv* {definition} {\vspace{-\baselineskip}} {}
```

plus a `\AfterEnvEnd` to be able to use the end environment hook to insert the code.  If you want to scan multiple environments, you need nested calls:

```latex
\ScanEnv* {definition} {\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
  {\ScanEnv* {definition*} {\vspace{-\baselineskip}} {}}
```

> [image]

Here's the code:

```latex
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \AfterEnvEnd { +m }
  { \jinwen_after_env_end:nw {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jinwen_after_env_end:nw #1 #2
       \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi
  { #2 \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi #1 }
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand \ScanEnv { s m +m+m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \jinwen_scan_env_ignore_par:nTF }
      { \jinwen_scan_env:nTF }
          {#2} {#3} {#4}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jinwen_scan_env:nTF
  { \__jinwen_scan_env:NnTF \c_false_bool }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jinwen_scan_env_ignore_par:nTF
  { \__jinwen_scan_env:NnTF \c_true_bool }
\tl_new:N \l__jinwen_collected_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__jinwen_scan_env:NnTF #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__jinwen_collected_tl
    \peek_analysis_map_inline:n
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jinwen_collected_tl {##1}
        \int_compare:nNnTF { "##3 } = { 0 }
          {
            \exp_args:No \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF {##1} \begin
              { \peek_analysis_map_break:n { \__jinwen_chk_env:nTFn {#2} {#3} {#4} } }
              {
                \bool_lazy_and:nnF {#1}
                    { \exp_args:No \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN {##1} \par }
                  { \__jinwen_scan_env_end:n {#4} }
              }
          }
          { \int_compare:nNnF { "##3 } = { 10 } { \__jinwen_scan_env_end:n {#4} } }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__jinwen_scan_env_end:n #1
  { \peek_analysis_map_break:n { \__jinwen_reinsert_tokens:nn {#1} { } } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__jinwen_reinsert_tokens:nn #1 #2
  {
    \use:x
      {
        \tl_clear:N \exp_not:N \l__jinwen_collected_tl
        \exp_not:n {#1} \l__jinwen_collected_tl #2
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__jinwen_chk_env:nTFn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \exp_args:Nx \__jinwen_reinsert_tokens:nn
      { \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {#4} { \exp_not:n {#2} } { \exp_not:n {#3} } } { {#4} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{definition}{enhanced jigsaw,pad at break*=1mm,breakable,
left=4mm,right=4mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
% beforeafter skip balanced=0pt,
colback=orange!10,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={1.5mm}{-1mm}{green!50!black},arc=.7mm}

\newtcolorbox{definition*}{enhanced jigsaw,pad at break*=1mm,breakable,
left=4mm,right=4mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
% beforeafter skip balanced=0pt,
colback=red!10,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={1.5mm}{-1mm}{green!50!black},arc=.7mm}

\def\scandefinitionenv{%
  \AfterEnvEnd{%
    \ScanEnv*{definition}%
      {\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%
      {\ScanEnv*{definition*}%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%
        {}}}}

\AddToHook{env/definition/end}{\scandefinitionenv}%
\AddToHook{env/definition*/end}{\scandefinitionenv}%

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  This is followed by text
\end{definition}

something else

\begin{definition}
  This is followed by another definition
\end{definition}

\begin{definition*}
  See, no gap :)
\end{definition*}

\begin{quote}
  some other environment
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have one more question: if I have `definition` and `definition*`, is it possible to make them identical in the scan? I tried to add `\ScanEnv*{definition*}` after `definition`, `\ScanEnv*{definition}` and `\ScanEnv*{definition*}` after `definition*`, but then `\begin{definition}` or `\begin{definition*}` after `end{definition*}` doesn't get scan.

Comment: @Jinwen Your approach (if I understood it right) was correct, but my implementation left some debris in the way and the scanning stopped too early.  Should work now