# Automatically replace some macro sequences in the document

Tags: macros

I wonder if there's some way to automatically replace

```
\AAA (...) \BBB
```

with `\CCC`, where `(...)` stand for a sequence made up with whitespace and `\par`, such as `\par \par\par`.

(I'm looking for a solution with LaTeX, not, say, using the regex replacement feature of the editor)

Below is an example to play with.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\AAA{A}
\def\BBB{B}
\def\CCC{C}

\begin{document}

% C
\AAA\BBB

% C
\AAA    \BBB

% C
\AAA  \par  \BBB

% C
\AAA

\BBB

% C
\AAA \par \par\par \BBB

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only really doable if you can redefine `\AAA` or wrap the whole thing in a macro, like `\replaceAAA{ ... \AAA <stuff> \BBB ... }`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik To my real usage, `\AAA` is `\end{theorem}`, and `\BBB` is `\begin{theorem}`. I can of course append something to them if needed.

Comment: This smells like an [XY question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/134574) to me (so please state your real use case in the question).  You can redefine `\end{theorem}` to grab until the next `\begin{theorem}`, but what happens at the last `\end{theorem}` in the document?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This is an attempt to solve [my first unanswered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505511/properly-connecting-adjacent-tcolorboxes). I believe this is definitely possible but never came up with a nice solution.

Comment: One question: can we always guarantee that a `\BBB` will follow a `\AAA`, or might the last occurrence in the document be an `\AAA`?

Comment: Also, FYI, `\AAA` is not the same as `\end{theorem}`, since the first is a single token, and the latter is not.  Any method that might work might be examining tokens, so it is important to state the problem clearly.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes In my use case, `\BBB` is `\begin{theorem}`, `\AAA` is `\end{theorem}`, so every `\BBB` will have a `\AAA` after it, but not vice versa.

Comment: @Jinwen Ah, so you want to scan ahead of an `\end{tcolorbox}` (or whatever environment) looking for a `\begin{tcolorbox}` and act accordingly.  That's _a lot_ easier :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik really? I thought it would be difficult as my old question has never been answered. Could you please tell me how to do this? I've been thinking over it for almost an year.

Comment: @Jinwen Question statistics in this site are weird.  Don't take a “nobody answered” as a “cannot be answered”: the time and day you post the question have a big role on how many people see it, but also how you write the question, and a lot of other factors _before_ the actual difficulty.  This network has the bounty system so that you can attract more attention to your question too. (I'm writing an answer for your other question)

Comment: your "real" usage comment shows that it is more or less unrelated to the question. The facilities for trapping `\AAA... \BBB` and replacing by `\CCC` are almost entirely different from trapping an environment such as `\begin{theorem}` I suggest you re-write the question to ask the question you want to ask. and please _always_ include a complete small test document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question as asked, you can define `\AAA` to scan ahead for `\BBB` and replace by `\CCC`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\AAA{A}
\def\BBB{B}
\def\CCC{C}


\long\def\AAA#1\BBB{\CCC}

\begin{document}

% C
\AAA\BBB

% C
\AAA    \BBB

% C
\AAA  \par  \BBB

% C
\AAA

\BBB

% C
\AAA \par \par\par \BBB

\end{document}
```

---

Or if you want to check there is only `\par` and white space, step through more slowly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\AAA{A}
\def\BBB{B}
\def\CCC{C}

\makeatletter
\let\oldAAA\AAA
\def\AAA{\@ifnextchar\BBB
   {\CCC\@gobble}{\@ifnextchar\par{\expandafter\AAA\@gobble}\oldAAA}}

\begin{document}

% C
\AAA\BBB

% C
\AAA    \BBB

% C
\AAA  \par  \BBB

% C
\AAA

\BBB

% C
\AAA \par \par\par \BBB

%A1B
\AAA 1\BBB

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I meant that the part between `\AAA` and `\BBB` can only contain `\par` or whitespace. In other cases this replacement shouldn't occur.

Comment: @Jinwen OK, added a slower loop that checks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\peek_regex_remove_once:nTF`

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\AAA}{}
 {
  \peek_regex_remove_once:nTF { (\s|\c{par})*? \c{BBB} } { \CCC } { A }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\BBB}{B}
\newcommand{\CCC}{C}

\begin{document}

% A
\AAA xxx

% C
\AAA\BBB

% C
\expandafter\AAA\space    \BBB

% C
\AAA  \par  \BBB

% C
\AAA

\BBB

% C
\AAA \par \par\par \BBB

\end{document}
```

The macro will scan ahead until finding something that doesn't match the regular expression, namely any number of spaces and `\par` tokens followed by `\BBB`. If it finds a match, it will output `\CCC`, ignoring the tokens that matched the regex; otherwise `A` followed by the tokens as if nothing had been scanned.

[image]

Comment: Would it work if I append such a macro to the end of some `\end{environmentname}`, to detect if there're only `\par` or whitespacing before the next `\begin{environmentname}`?

Comment: @Jinwen Possibly. You should be clearer about your aims, when asking questions. Your examples are often too scanty about the real aim. *What* is the real application you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, I admit this. I often misunderstand the real difficulty of a problem when extracting a MWE from a long document. What I thought easy to solve often turns out to be more difficult than my original propose.

Answer (score 2):

Created a `tokcycle` envoronment `\nospace...\endnospace` that does the task.  Caveats: It does not screen out line-ending macro spaces `\` , and it will screen out spaces and pars after `theorem` environments to the next `\begin`, whether that next `\begin` is a `{theorem}` or any other environment.

If any other character, other than  , `\par`, and `\`  occurs before the next `\begin`, all those collected tokens are dumped into the stream, along with the disqualifying token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newenvironment{theorem}{Theo\ignorespaces}{rem}
\def\comparitor{theorem}
\newif\ifeligible
\newtoks\stuff
\def\dumpit{\eligiblefalse\addcytoks[1]{\the\stuff}\stuff{}}
\def\clearit{\eligiblefalse\stuff{}}
\long\def\addstuff#1{\stuff\expandafter{\the\stuff#1}}
\tokcycleenvironment\nospace
{\dumpit\addcytoks{##1}}
{\def\tmp{##1}\ifx\tmp\comparitor\global\eligibletrue\fi\addcytoks{##1}}
{\tctestifcon{\ifeligible}%
  {\tctestifx{\par##1}%
    {\addstuff{##1}}%
    {\tctestifx{\ ##1}%
      {\addstuff{##1}}%
      {\tctestifx{\begin##1}%
        {\clearit}%
        {\dumpit}%
      \addcytoks{##1}%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {\addcytoks{##1}}%
}
{\ifeligible\addstuff{##1}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
\begin{document}
\nospace
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\par\ \ \par

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}  \begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}   \begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

abc

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

abc\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

Failure mode: line-ending explicit spaces 

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}\ \ \ 
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\endnospace
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You code is a little too complicated for me. My guess is that you code replaces `\par` and whitespace with `\stuff`, which is set to empty. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jinwen When `{theorem}` is detected, it starts checking tokens.  If `\par`s, spaces, or macro spaces are detected, it sets them in `\stuff`.  If a `\begin` comes along, it throws away `\stuff`; but if some other type of token comes along, it sets `\the\stuff` in the output stream, resets it, and continues on until it hits another `{theorem}`.