# \skip_vertical:n and \vspace between two tcolorbox environments

Tags: tcolorbox, tex-core, expl3

What is the difference between `\skip_vertical:n` and `\vspace`? In the following example, the `\skip_vertical:n` has no effect, but if one changes it to `\vspace` then it works. Why is this?

*I'm using an up-to-date TeX Live 2022 (2022-07-31), if that helps. It seems that this problem didn't exist two months ago.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_vertical:n { -\baselineskip }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

---

Background

*In the package `colorist` I adopted the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587023/194994) of Phelype Oleinik to connect the color boxes of adjacent definitions. Since the package is itself written in `expl3`, I changed the `\vspace` to `\skip_vertical:n`.*

*This works fine until one month ago. This morning, when I was trying to recompile the documentation, I noticed that the old code in my package fails to work, and after a bit debugging, it turns out that it is the `\skip_vertical:n` between two `tcolobox` that fails to work.*

Answer (score 1):

In vertical mode, `\vspace{...}` is essentially `\vskip ... \vskip 0pt` whereas `\skip_vertical:n`  is `\vskip ...`

so apart from some differences in etex dimension expression handling, the main difference is that `\vspace` adds an additional zero skip, which will show up if you query `\lastskip`